# file_get_contents of php, doesn't provide proper error response of a https request

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a GET Response from HereMaps Geocoding API as follows:

```
$hmaps_request = "https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey={MY_API_KEY}&q=3891+Delwood+Drive%2C+Powell%2C+OH%2C+United+States;
$json_details = json_decode($hmaps_request);
```

I get successful response when all params are right and in proper JSON Format too. But When I provide wrong API Key I get Error as follows:

```
local.ERROR:Error occurred while geocoding file_get_contents(https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey={MY_API_KEY}&q=3891+Delwood+Drive%2C+Powell%2C+OH%2C+United+States): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

I Tried the same using Postman and got proper error response like this with a 401 Status code:

```
{
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "error_description": "apiKey invalid. apiKey not found."
}
```

Also tried the code snippets provided by postman, but since its a HTTPS, I have to provide certificate it seems. Any way to get proper error response using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this behavior by setting `http.ignore_errors` to true.

```php
<?php

$opts = [
    "http" => [
        'ignore_errors' => true
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$hmaps_request = file_get_contents("https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey={MY_API_KEY}&q=3891+Delwood+Drive%2C+Powell%2C+OH%2C+United+States", false, $context);

$json_details = json_decode($hmaps_request);

/* Output 
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(12) "Unauthorized"
  ["error_description"]=>
  string(33) "apiKey invalid. apiKey not found."
}
*/
var_dump($json_details);
```

Comment: Thanks, This is working. Is there any way to get the status code from this response too?

Comment: yes, change the var_dump line, to: `var_dump($json_details, $http_response_header);`. In the variable `$http_response_header` you can see the list of response headers.